# Install remotebuild on Mac failed with „uid must be an unsigned int“

Tags: node.js, macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015, npm

I´ve tried to install remotebuild on my Mac for deploying Cordova apps in Visual Studio 2015 over my mac.

technical information:
macOS Sierra
node v4.6.0
npm  v3.10.8
xcode 8

But it fails with the following error: „uid must be an unsigned int“

I tried it with reinstalling npm without success.

```
$ sudo npm install -g remotebuild

npm WARN deprecated wrench@1.5.9: wrench.js is deprecated! You should check out fs-extra (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) for any operations you were using wrench for. Thanks for all the usage over the years.
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "remotebuild"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8

npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Darwin 16.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "remotebuild"
npm ERR! node v4.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
....
npm ERR! uid must be an unsigned int
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it fails with the following error: „uid must be an unsigned int“

This is a known issue, the root cause is in Node.js core where the `UID` for `nobody` on OS X, which is `-2` converted to an unsigned integer, would be returned as a signed integer by `fs.stat()`. See the discussion in Github [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13918). This issue only exists in `npm v3.10.8`.

And the fix has been updated. Please see [fs: fix handling of `struct stat` fields #8515](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/8515).

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the issue by reseting the permissions of node modules to your ID:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

For the record, this happens with many different issues installing with nom like installing Cordova:

```
npm install -g cordova
```